# restrict access to elasticsearch

Tags: security, elasticsearch

I built a simple web interface with a search box where users can type quires. However I want to block users from seeing or accessing directly to port 9200 which ES listens to, so no user can retrieve information from ES without going through the interface, nor can modify the index in any way, through the interface or not. Right now when I type localhost:9200 or 127.0.0.1:9200, I can see the entire ES indices,e.g., http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v. Any suggestion on how to do it?

Comment: Would ES and the application be running on the same machine?

Answer (score 0):

If other user has access to localhost, The only remains action is using [Shield](https://www.elastic.co/products/shield), the ES application to protect Cluster.

But If you can limit the access to ES not from localhost, you can bind ES only to localhost or using firewall to restrict access to port 9200:

in `/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml`:

`network.bind_host: 127.0.0.1`

OR

`iptables -A INPUT -s !127.0.0.1 -m tcp --dport 9200 -j DROP`